# Why do I feel a force from a non-accelerating punch?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity, mass, acceleration

If I'm getting punched by a fist that is moving at a constant velocity (let's say $20 \mathrm{m/s}$), I still feel a force that is being applied to my body. However, according to $F=ma$, in order to feel a force, the object needs to be accelerating. Then, how can a non-accelerating object apply a force to me?

Comment: Duplicate of [Newton's second law explanation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/520703/179151)

Comment: Also [If a vehicle with constant velocity hits me then is it correct to say that the vehicle exerted no force upon me and therefore I am unhurt?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/545479/179151)

Comment: Please clarify in your question: did you accelerate as a result of the punch, and if not are there any other forces acting on you?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the force $F=ma$ can generally be defined as the rate of change of linear momentum in a certain direction i.e. $$F=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{d(mv)}{dt}$$
For constant mass of the body i.e. $m=\text{constant}$, $$F=\frac{d(mv)}{dt}=\frac{mdv}{dt}=ma$$ 
Above formula is Newton's second law for a body of constant mass $m$ moving with constant acceleration $a$ which is a specific case of generalized definition.

When the fist moving with a constant (initial) velocity say $v=20\mathrm{m/s}$ hits your body the velocity becomes almost zero in certain time $t$ thus the linear momentum of fist becomes zero at this moment. This causes a change in linear momentum in certain time i.e. $mv/t$ which is the force (by definition) experienced by your body in the direction of moving fist.

Comment: Consider looking at the possible duplicates pointed out in the comments before answering the question.